# Laravel dropzone not accepting office files

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm implementing dropzone in laravel. It works with images, but when I want to upload for example a .docx file it's telling me:

> file has to be a type of: jpg, jpeg, png, bmp

I've done it like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomDropzone = {
        maxFilesize: 2,
        acceptedFiles: 'png,docx',
        parallelUploads: 30,
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Sleep hier uw bestanden in, of klik op mij.'
    };
```

--EDIT--

This is my html for dropzone:

```
 <div class="well well bs-component">
                <div class="bs-component">
                    <form action="/{{ $user->id }}/files" method="post" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomDropzone" accept="pdf">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have an `accept` attribute defined on the `input` element?

Comment: @Bogdan Please see my edit